# C++ constructor errors

Tags: c++, parsing, constructor

I am writing a parser for a compiler . So for the constructor I have the code :

```
//constructor
Parser::Parser(char* file)
{
  MyLex(file) ; 
}
```

Upon compiling using **g++ parsy.cpp parsydriver.cpp** , I am however getting this error saying :

```
parsy.cpp: In constructor ‘Parser::Parser(char*)’:
parsy.cpp:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘Lex::Lex()’
lexy2.h:34: note: candidates are: Lex::Lex(char*)
lexy2.h:31: note:                 Lex::Lex(const Lex&)
parsy.cpp:15: error: no match for call to ‘(Lex) (char*&)’
```

Where am I going wrong ? **Lex myLex** is declared as **private** in the Parser header . I am at my wit's end . I tried using this :

```
//constructor
Parser::Parser(char* file):myLex(file)
{ 
}
```

My Lexical Analyser constructor is :

```
Lex::Lex(char* filename): ch(0) 
{
  //Set up the list of reserved words
  reswords[begint] = "BEGIN";
  reswords[programt] = "PROGRAM";
  reswords[constt] = "CONST";
  reswords[vart] = "VAR";
  reswords[proceduret] = "PROCEDURE";
  reswords[ift] = "IF";
  reswords[whilet] = "WHILE";
  reswords[thent] = "THEN";
  reswords[elset] = "ELSE";
  reswords[realt] = "REAL";
  reswords[integert] = "INTEGER";
  reswords[chart] = "CHAR";
  reswords[arrayt] = "ARRAY";
  reswords[endt] = "END";

  //Open the file for reading
  file.open(filename);
}
```

but, this creates a bunch of undefined reference to Lexical Analyser file and functions ! 
I have included the files properly. But so far , I don't understand how to get over this problem.

**UPDATE**
The header file inclusions are :

parsy.h file :

```
#ifndef PARSER_H
#define PARSER_H

// other library file includes

#include "lexy2.h"
class Parser
{
}...
```

parsy.cpp file :

```
// usual ilbraries

#include "parsy.h"

using namespace std ;

Parser::Parser(char* file) ....
```

parsydriver.cpp :

```
// usual libraries
#include "parsy.h"
using namespace std ;

int main()
..
```

lexy2.cpp file :

I have included the lexy2.h file. Should I be including the parser header files in the lexical analyser ones ? Doesn't seem likely. But how should I tackle them then ?

Comment: The second way is the proper way. The problems would still exist had the first worked. They're linker errors that sprout from you not linking correctly in some form.

Comment: how can the linker errors be overcome ? I will edit and update the question where I put my header file includes.

Comment: Take your pick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: is parser derived from Lex? if so construct Lex before parser. If not derived then too construct Lex first. u said u declared myLex in the header. that means u declared with a default constructor? if so that is the cause as u have no defined the default constructor. try to declare a pointer to lex in the header and not the variable itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code inside constructor runs when object is already constructed. Your class `MyLex` does not have default constructor. So you have to define default constructor or it should be:

```
//constructor
Parser::Parser(char* file): MyLex(file)
{
}
```

If you have "undefined symbol" linker errors then you forgot to add some `.cpp` files (maybe lexy2.cpp) to the project or compiler command line. Assuming that all undefined symbols located in lexy2.cpp then try `g++ parsy.cpp parsydriver.cpp lexy2.cpp`.

Comment: ok so I have 4 files + 1driver file . how should I be compiling it in the shell?

files are : lexy2.h lexy2.cpp parsy.h parsy.cpp  and parsydriver.cpp